# How enable or disable correctly an Action

Tags: java, action, menuitem, toolbar, netbeans-platform

i have a little problem when i try to disable an Action of my Netbeans platform project. When the app starts, some Actions must be disabled, and i do that with this method:

```
CallableSystemAction.get(BuildProjectAction.class).setEnabled(FLAG);
```

It works, because the BuildProjectAction is disabled, but the corresponding items of the MenuBar and the Toolbar remains enabled until i click on one of it.
Only later that i have clicked on it, the comportament start to work correctly.
First question: **Why?**

If i want disable an Action, it's obvious that i want disable also the relative Icon in the Menu and in the Toolbar, so it must be automatic when i call `Action.setEnabled(false)`.
It doesn't have sense that the Icons are not refreshed if i don't click on they.

Same problem if i try to use `.getToolbarPresenter().setEnabled(false);` and `.getMenuPresenter().setEnabled(false);`

For start the application with the icons disabled, I have tried to set the lazy attribute to FALSE and declare the image programmatically with the method `setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));` that sets the same image for Menu and Toolbar.

And it works; there is only another problem: Menu and Toolbar have icons of different size (16x16 and 24x24).

It doesn't have sense that the if i set the icon with the `@ActionRegistration(iconBase = "image.png")` the correct icon is automatically selected, but if i use the method `.setIcon()`, it doesn't.

I have read some articles about Action, CookieAction, Lookup, but the only thing that i want is disable the graphic elements in the same moment when i disable the Action.
Second question: How i can do that?

This is an example of my Action.

```
@ActionID(
        category = "Run",
        id = "BuildProjectAction")
@ActionRegistration(
        lazy = true,
        iconBase = "images/icons/compile.png",
        displayName = "#CTL_BuildProjectAction")
@ActionReferences({
        @ActionReference(
                path = "Menu/Run",
                position = 3),
        @ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/Run",
                position = 3),
        @ActionReference(
                path = "Shortcuts",
                name = "D-B")
})
@Messages("CTL_BuildProjectAction=Build Project")
public final class BuildProjectAction extends CallableSystemAction {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {...}

@Override
public void performAction() {}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return Bundle.CTL_BuildProjectAction();
}

@Override
public HelpCtx getHelpCtx() {
    return HelpCtx.DEFAULT_HELP;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to create an action that is disabled at startup is to use the platform’s New Action Wizard to create your action, and to create one that depends on a "context" -- this is, on finding a specific object in the global lookup. If no object is available in the lookup, as at startup, then the action will be disabled.

The menu and toolbar graphic elements are bundled together with your action via the annotations. This means that enabled/disabled state of your context-aware action will automatically affect the icons in the menu and toolbar as well.

This article by Geertjan Wielenga has a walkthrough on creating a context-aware action:

http://netbeans.dzone.com/how-to-make-context-sensitive-actions

When you want to enable your action, you will add the object on which the action depends into the global lookup, which will cause the action (and its graphic elements) to be enabled.

This entry in the platform’s Developer FAQ has some examples of how to add an object to the global context:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqAddGlobalContext

If you need to create an action that depends on a more complex set of conditions there is some discussion, as well as a code sample illustrating how to do this, in this platform developer list thread:

http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic55295.html

The grayed-out versions of the icons that are shown when your action is disabled are created automatically by the platform. You only have to provide the "normal" non-grayed-out images.

As for the icons of different sizes, it’s a matter of filename convention. If your annotation declares the icon with `@ActionRegistration(iconBase = "image.png”)`, then you will provide a 16x16 image called “image.png” and a 24x24 version called “image24.png”. The platform will find and use the appropriate size in the menu and toolbar.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply.
I had already read the pages that have you said, but I wanted to try to avoid the use of Cookie.

The Actions that i want to enable not depends by an element selected in a TopComponent, but from to a click on a Button "New project"; for this reason, i have avoid the use of the Cookie.

Do you know if is possible to define a boolean variable (ie  "program_started = true") that said if the user have clicked on the Button "New project" and associate at his  value the Actions that i want enable/disable?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm on the same boat. The context works, but I have a play button I would like to disable while the previous run is still going on.